# Count getSingleton Product Collection Without changing it?

Tags: product-collection

How can i count an productcollection without changing it?

when i do:

```
$test = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('special_price', 150);
```

And then call count($test) it replaces my productcollection.

EDIT:

Basicly i want this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('special_price', array('gt' => 0))->getSize();
```

To count how many products has a special price. But when i call this code, it replaces my product collection, so it only shows products with special_price

Comment: did you try to use `$test->getSize()` ?

Comment: The problem is, it replaces my productcollection even before i call $test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a method.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
->getProductCollection()
->getSelectCountSql()
->where('special_price > 0')
->query()
->fetchColumn();
```

This seems a bit odd... so please tell me, if anyone got a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please use $count = $test->getSize();

dont use count directly to collection.

Comment: Ok.  I will. But... still doesnt solve my problem with the productcollection getting replaced :-(

Comment: Brittany, would you like to post the code for collection? So that we can easily understand and solving your problem quickly.

Comment: I tried to edit my question now. Hope it makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('special_price', 150)->count();
```

OR

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->addFieldToFilter('special_price', 150)->count();
```

Comment: Same result, still replacing my active collection :/

Comment: @BrittanyMoore Pl check my updated answer

Comment: The counting is perfect.. but the problem is, it replaces all my products, so it only shows those with special price at 150... i only want the number, not to replace all products :/

Comment: @BrittanyMoore, now check updated answer

Comment: But the problem with getmodel is, that i dont get the sorting it is already making, so basicly i want the active collection to be counted, not a new one

Answer (score 0):

Just make a clone of that collection then you will get count from clone collection

> ```
> $cloneLayerCollection =clone Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();
> $size = $cloneLayerCollection->addFieldToFilter('special_price', array('gt' => 0))->getSize();
> ```

Comment: I tried that, but actually it still makes changes to my collection on the cloned one.

Answer (score 0):

EAV queries work by creating conditions and inner joins against related tables.  So even if you were to remove the where clause of your select statement, you would still be left with an inner join that would mess up your query.

You could perform a `reset()`, but you would be left with an empty query.

The initial select statement is built with the `_initSelect()` method, which is protected, and is called in the constructor of the parent class.

Your best bet is to instantiate a new instance to establish the count.

```
$countCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', '150)
    ->getSize();
```